# Correct way to replace a default gesture recognizer in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to disable the default long-press gesture recognizer in a UITextField so that I can add my own long-press gesture recognizer. My code for doing this looks like this:

```
    for recognizer:UIGestureRecognizer in textField.gestureRecognizers as! [UIGestureRecognizer] {
        if recognizer is UILongPressGestureRecognizer{
        recognizer = myCustomRecognizer
        }
    }
```

But this gives me a runtime-error saying it found nil while unwrapping an optional value, which makes me think it's not finding any gesture recognizers? Is this the correct way to do it?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that the `UITextField` is not using gesture recognizers in the internal implementation, and instead, is directly handling the touch events from the `UIControl` [methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW24).

Therefore, I think you have a few options, since you are trying to still use the same touch behavior, I would suggest you look at the `UITextFieldDelegate` [methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW2) and see if you can't override the behavior that way. Specifically, the [textFieldShouldBeginEditing:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldBeginEditing:) method.

If that won't allow you to accomplish what you're attempting, then you will have to create a custom subclass of `UITextField` and implement the touch events yourself. This should only be attempted though as a last resort.

> Even if you subclass, you can still use the parent class behavior by calling super in each method you override.